# How to bring data from Twitter API and show last tweets

Tags: reactjs, json, twitter

I've been looking for a while for this, even inside the Twitter API but I still don't understand how to connect it with my React App. Everything I found is backend and specifically for Node.

Is there a way to connect my React App with my Twitter account just to show the last 5 tweets?

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to get started with implementing the Node server. It will be responsible for making the actual requests to the Twitter API. This Node server will serve as a proxy between your React App and the Twitter APIs. On your Node server, you will need to create APIs endpoints that connect to the filtered stream endpoints.

[Here is a guide](https://dev.to/twitterdev/building-an-app-to-stream-tweets-in-real-time-using-the-twitter-api-o31) that may help you